# Why there is a border around the UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xcode5

In my story board I have added a new custom view controller. It is 'connected' to the RootView Controller via a push segue.

This is the new custom UIViewController as seen in the storyboard

[image]

When I run my app in the simulator, I can see a border around the frame. (Of course it is visible because I set a background color to RootViewController)

[image]

I want to understand:

1) Why my custom view controller does not occupy the whole frame?

2) what is the orange color dotted line? Is it related to the question 1? What is the best practice (i.e. is the border a new behaviour and is not indicative of bad design etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orange dotted line shows that the view will change when the constraints are resolved, and shows where the view will end up.

If the view is correct in Interface Builder, just go to the Resolve Auto Layout Issues popup menu and select Update Constraints. That will update the constraint values to match the layout in Interface Builder.

If you select Update Frames instead, that will make the view match the constraints (causing the view to shrink to the orange dotted line in this case).

[image: Update Constraints]